# C# SocketAsyncEventArgs not sending all data

Tags: c#

I have a problem with the SocketAsyncEventArgs class..the problem is when I try to send 8K of data
for example over internet, the socket sometimes only sends 1K or 2K, I know that this is normal for
TCP socket and that one send doesn't guarantee one receive.
now for this to work for me I modified my code to resend the remaining data, for example
when I the SocketAsyncEventArgs.SendAsync completes, in the callback i check whether it sent all the 8K or not if it's not, I call the SocketAsyncEventArgs.SendAsync again with the remaining data untill
I send it all.
Now, when I looked at some SocketAsyncEventArgs code.. I saw that most people don't do so!
and they just clean up when the send complete without checking if it sent all the data or not!
also when I looked at Microsoft's example, they were saying the ONE call to SocketAsyncEventArgs.SendAsync guarantees that all the data will be sent.
I mean I tested it myself and NO all data will not be sent in one call to SocketAsyncEventArgs.SendAsync.
What I'm doing wrong ?
thanks in advance.

Edit:
Here is the code which doesn't send all data(exactly like microsoft's)
the SendAsyncComplete will be called when the socket sends for example 1Kb of data
not all 8K!

```
public virtual void Send(byte[] packet, int offset, int length)
{
    if (_tcpSock != null && _tcpSock.Connected)
    {
        var args = SocketHelpers.AcquireSocketArg();
        if (args != null)
        {
            args.Completed += SendAsyncComplete;
            args.SetBuffer(packet, offset, length);
            args.UserToken = this;

            var willRaiseEvent = _tcpSock.SendAsync(args);
            if (!willRaiseEvent)
            {
            ProcessSend(args);
            }
            unchecked
            {
                _bytesSent += (uint)length;
            }
            Interlocked.Add(ref _totalBytesSent, length);
        }
        else
        {
            log.Error("Client {0}'s SocketArgs are null", this);
        }
    }
}

private static void ProcessSend(SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
{
      args.Completed -= SendAsyncComplete;
      SocketHelpers.ReleaseSocketArg(args);   
}

private static void SendAsyncComplete(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs args)
{
    ProcessSend(args);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could post some of your code to show us how you are working? Maybe then we can help you. :)

Comment: ok, I've edited my post with sample code, thanks

Comment: It isn't crystal from the snippet but do consider that SendAsync will often return true.  Indicating that the send was completed immediately and that the Complete method isn't going to be called.

Comment: yes I check for whether it completed immediately or not and call the
SendAsyncComplete method myself, but this is not the issue here.

Comment: Did you check the SocketError property in the Complete event? Complete is not only called for successful send operations!

Comment: i've edited the code to be more clear..
Hansjoerg:if you mean socketerror.success, why should I do this
I mean i saw no one doing so !
also when I edited my code to send the remaining data, it sent it all with no errors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many things I would change there. As a preamble, read [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/socketasynceventargs.aspx).

First of all, whenever you sent any data on the socket, you must process that event: either you stop the whole send process, or you issue another socket send operation to send the remaining data.

So it makes sense to have 3 methods, like this:

```
// This is the Send() to be used by your class' clients
1) public void Send(byte[] buffer);
```

This method will take care to apply any data formatting that you need, create (retrieve) a SocketAsyncEventArgs object, set the token to hold your buffer, and call the next method bellow:

```
2) private void Send(SocketAsyncEventArgs e);
```

This one actually calls 
    Socket.SendAsync(SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
and copies the contents from the token (the buffer, remember?) to the SAEA object. Now that is why because method number (2) might be called several times to send the remaining data that couldn't be sent in one operation by the socket. So here you copy the remaining data from the token to the SAEA buffer.

```
3) private void ProcessSent(SocketAsyncEventArgs e);
```

This last method will examine the data that has been sent by the socket. If all the data has been sent, the SAEA object will be released. If not, method (2) will be called again for the rest of the data. In order to keep track of sent data, you use SAEA.BytesTransferred. You should add this value to a value stored in the custom token I advise you to create (so do not use "this" as a token).

This is where you also check for SocketError on the SAEA parameter.

This last method will be called in two places:

- in the 2nd method, like this:

  ```
      // Attempt to send data in an asynchronous fashion
      bool isAsync = this.Socket.SendAsync(e);

      // Something went wrong and we didn't send the data async
      if (!isAsync)
          this.ProcessSent(e);
  ```

This bit is important any many people missed it even when using the more traditional Begin/EndXXX pattern (in that case, via IAsyncResult). If you don't place it, once in a while (quite rare), a StackOverflow exception will pop out of nowhere and will keep you puzzled for long time.

- in the Completed event handler:

  ```
  private void Completed(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
  {
      // What type of operation did just completed?
      switch (e.LastOperation)
      {
          case SocketAsyncOperation.Send:
              {
                  ProcessSent(e);
                  break;
              }
      }
  }
  ```

The tricky thing is to use one SocketAsyncEventArgs object per 1st Send(byte[]) operation, and release it in 3rd operation, if all data has been sent.

For that, you must create a custom token (class or immutable struct) to place in SocketAsyncEventArgs.UserToken inside the 1st method, and then keep track of how much data you have transferred on each Socket.SendAsync() operation.

When you are reading the article provided in the beginning, notice how the writer reuses the same SAEA object when at the end of Send() operation proceeds with a Receive() operation, if all the data has been sent. That is because his protocol is: each one of the parties (server and client) talk to each other in turns.

Now, should multiple calls to the 1st Send() method occur at the same time, there is no rule in which order they will be handled by the OS. If that is likely to happen and message order is important, and since any call to Send(byte[]) from an "outside entity" result in a Socket.SendAsync(), I suggest that the 1st method actually writes down the received bytes in an internal buffer. As long as this buffer is not empty, you keep sending this data internally. Think of it like a producer-consumer scenario, where the "outside entity" is the producer and the internal send op is the consumer. I prefer an optimistic concurrency scenario here.

The documentation on the matter is rather shallow, with the exception of this article, and even in this case, when you start implementing your own application, some things turn out to be different. This SocketAsyncEventArgs model is arguably a bit counter-intuitive.

Let me know if you need more help, I had my times of struggle with this a while ago when I developed my own library.

Edit:

If I were you, I would move

```
unchecked
{
    _bytesSent += (uint)length;
}
Interlocked.Add(ref _totalBytesSent, length);
```

to your ProcessSend(SAEA), and use args.BytesTransferred instead of "length".

Comment: first of all, thanks "Vladimir" and you all for help..
Vladimir:
I already have something similar to this what you've said and it's working ok, but this is not the problem, I mean the problem is not how to make this setup to send all the data, I already did so.
my concern is that I saw many code that doesn't have this check
also how come that microsoft said that the SAEA SendAsync is redundant and it will send all the data for you ?
even in their example they did not check for the data being sent if it's equal to what they've sent or not.

Comment: True enough, but that only works as long as the buffer you wish to send through SendAsync() does not exceed the Socket's internal buffer - which will have a decent size, like 32k. But you will need that "recursive" send once your piece of information exceeds that buffer.

Comment: mmm, the buffer I assign to the SAEA is 8K and I know that the internal buffer for the socket is larger or equal than the buffer I gave to it, but even with that the SAEA sometimes doesn't send all data!

Comment: Do you call your method like: Send(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) in your code only once for this 8k message? Are you aware that is very possible that the program cursor reaches the unchecked{} block or Interlocked.Add(ref _totalBytesSent, length) before sending the data? Would that affect your send process?

Comment: No that doesn't affect my send process, but I think I figured it out..
I think it's because i call the SendAsync multible times as you said with another 8K packet and the main TCP socket has not yet sent all the last 8K so the call to SendAsync only sends what the socket buffer can take at this moment
for ex, if the socket internal buffer has an 8K buffer and I send 8K and the socket sent 2K of them..when I call SendAsync again with another 8K, the socket can only take another 2K to send, so the completed method will be called in this case with only 2K of data being sent, is this correct ?

Comment: If you issue concurrent SendAsync ops, the order they are being processed by the Socket might be changed. Anyroad, also make sure everything works well at the receiving end - maybe send works but the data you receive at the other end is not handled correctly.

Comment: At the receive end it works fine because every packet I send has a number and at the receive end I check for that number and if it's not the packet that should be preocessed I put it in a queue untill the right one come..
But now..how can I check if the socket has sent all it's data before starting another send operation ? shall I make a bool variable CanSend that set to true when the send operation completes
and now I assume that the first send operation will send all the data as long as it doesn't exceed the socket's internal buffer, is that correct ?

Comment: See edits under 3rd method and in the end. You could also serialize Send(SAEA) calls. Myself, I use optimistic concurrency in this scenario.

Comment: Let me be more clear..I already did this what you're saying
I have a public function Send(byte[] packet) that can be accessed from outside the class and that function calls the internal one
if the packet is greater that the MAXIMUMBUFFER internal property
I split the array in a queue to send it later, and when a send operation completes I check whether it send all the data or not
and if it's not I call the internal send function again with the remaining data to send, and I have flags contains how many data is remaining to be sent..

Comment: now wouldn't it be better to wait until the socket send all the data
and start a new send operation as long as Microsoft guarantees that all the socket buffer will be sent??
i mean first time the socket will send all the 8K huh ?
then it will call the completed method, in that method I set a global variable CanSend to true, and now a new send operation starts
from the thread that handles the send.
isn't this better ?